# WGPU: How to change max_bind_groups/device bind group limit?

Tags: rust, textures, wgpu-rs

I am trying to create multiple bind groups in wgpu (one for each texture I have to load) but it seems that my device can only support 4 bind groups: whenever I try to use more, I get the error "bind group layout count 5 exceeds device bind group limit 4".

From wgpu documentation it's not clear to me if this is an actual limit of the hardware device or if this is a soft limit and can be set in software. In https://docs.piston.rs/conrod/wgpu/struct.Limits.html, it mentions that the default of max_bind_groups is 4 which is the same as the max value in the error I get.

I think many applications use a lot more than 4 textures, and they all work on my device (even though likely not using wgpu?) so is it possible to change this limit and get rid of the error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> From wgpu documentation it's not clear to me if this is an actual limit of the hardware device or if this is a soft limit and can be set in software.

`wgpu` is designed so that (when things are working properly) you don't get *surprising* errors when you run your program on new hardware. So, the `Limits` *that you pass to `request_device()`* are always enforced, regardless of what the hardware supports. But if you specify limits that are higher than the hardware supports, `request_device()` will fail.

So, in general, you should specify `Limits` that are exactly as much as your application needs. If your application can be flexible, then consult [`Adapter::limits()`](https://docs.rs/wgpu/latest/wgpu/struct.Adapter.html#method.limits) to find out what is supported, then adjust that limit appropriately in your request.

> I think many applications use a lot more than 4 textures, and they all work on my device (even though likely not using wgpu?)

There are lots of ways in which the `max_bind_groups` limit is not a limit on texturing:

- Different draw calls can use different bind groups set with [`set_bind_group()`](https://docs.rs/wgpu/latest/wgpu/util/trait.RenderEncoder.html#tymethod.set_bind_group) — `max_bind_groups` is a limit on how many bind groups a pipeline uses *at the same time*, not on how many bind groups you can create.
- Each bind group can have many bindings.
- Each binding in a bind group can be an array of textures (if `Features::TEXTURE_BINDING_ARRAY` is supported).
- A texture may used as an *array texture* ([`D2Array`](https://docs.rs/wgpu/latest/wgpu/enum.TextureViewDimension.html#variant.D2Array)), which stores “layers” all of the same size but with different content.
- A texture may be used as a *texture atlas* — this is not a graphics-API feature, but simply the idea of using different parts of a texture for different purposes.

In a simple situation where you have mesh and texture assets, typically each mesh has an associated *material* (this is an abstraction you create in your code, not something in the graphics API) — the texture or textures it uses, and possibly other parameters controlling drawing. You create a bind group for each material, then when rendering, `set_bind_group()` for one material, draw all the objects that use that material, then `set_bind_group()` again, and so on. This uses only *one* bind group slot in the pipeline for the material, whichever material it is. You'd use at least another bind group for the camera — that's just 2 of the 4 slots you have available by default.

Of course, other kinds of rendering may in fact need access to many textures at once. That's when you use the other techniques in the list above.

Comment: I see, that explains it! I am particularly interested in the "Each bind group can have many bindings" approach. Default limit here seems to be very high, by default max_bindings_per_bind_group: 640, and my device has 65536. Is there any other limitation that you know of or is this the way to go?

Comment: @Redirectk The first question you need to consider is: does your pipeline (in particular your shader) need to _use all those textures simultaneously?_  If not, then you don't need to put all of them in the bind group. It would be a strange application that needs 640 textures simultaneously accessed by one draw. I suspect you may be making an incorrect assumption about what you need to do to achieve your goal, but I don't know what it is. Consider posting a new question which describes what you want to draw, and what role the textures play, and asking how best to organize and bind them.

Comment: Indeed, 640 is a limit I will never reach! :) My request for clarification was related to whether 640 is a reasonable limit to assume for any device in circulation. I only need ~8 textures simultaneously. I could assemble in a texture atlas/array however texture size limit will start to apply. I believe multiple bindings is the right solution. I just wanted to double check that I am not missing any disadvantage of this approach compared to the others you mentioned in your answer.